# Component is taking a lot of time when rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a Parent component where I display categories and filters and when the user click on one of them I call a function that fetches the data and display them

The problem is it takes to mush time to change a category and filter, maybe because the component is rendering many times. I tried to use `React.memo` for the sub components I have and did many things in this parent component but still the component is so Slow.

Here is my Parent Component:

```
...
function Explore() {
  const {theme, isDark} = useThemeContext();
  const isPortrait = useIsPortrait();
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const getDataFunc = (func) => dispatch.bind(null, func());
  const getTrending_Chefs = getDataFunc(getTrendingChefs);
  const getNew_Chefs = getDataFunc(getNewChefs);
  const getPopular_Chefs = getDataFunc(getPopularChefs);
  const getVerified_Chefs = getDataFunc(setVerifiedChefs);
  const getTrending_Recipes = getDataFunc(getTrendingRecipes);
  const getNew_Recipes = getDataFunc(getNewRecipes);
  const getPopular_Recipes = getDataFunc(getPopularRecipes);
  const getVerified_Recipes = getDataFunc(setVerifiedRecipes);

  const navigateTo =
    (screen, params = {}) =>
    () =>
      setTimeout(navigation.navigate, 0, screen, params);

  const categories = {
    chefs: {
      name: 'Chefs',
      title: getMessageByKey('explore.chefs'),
      image: ChefsCategory,
      available: true,
    },
    recipes: {
      name: 'Recipes',
      title: getMessageByKey('explore.recipes'),
      image: RecipesCategory,
      available: true,
    },
    products: {
      name: 'Products',
      title: getMessageByKey('explore.products'),
      image: ProductsCategory,
      available: false,
    },
    buisness: {
      name: 'Buisness',
      title: getMessageByKey('explore.buisness'),
      image: BuisnessCategory,
      available: false,
    },
  };

  const queries = {
    trending: {
      name: 'Trending',
      title: getMessageByKey('explore.trending'),
      image: <FireFilter style={styles.queryImage} />,
      selectedImage: <FireWhiteFilter style={styles.queryImage} />,
      dataFunc_Chefs: getTrending_Chefs,
      dataFunc_Recipes: getTrending_Recipes,
    },
    new: {
      name: 'New',
      title: getMessageByKey('explore.new'),
      image: <LightningFilter style={styles.queryImage} />,
      selectedImage: <LightningWhiteFilter style={styles.queryImage} />,
      dataFunc_Chefs: getNew_Chefs,
      dataFunc_Recipes: getNew_Recipes,
    },
    top: {
      name: 'Popular',
      title: getMessageByKey('explore.popular'),
      image: <HeartFilter style={styles.queryImage} />,
      selectedImage: <HeartWhiteFilter style={styles.queryImage} />,
      dataFunc_Chefs: getPopular_Chefs,
      dataFunc_Recipes: getPopular_Recipes,
    },
    verified: {
      name: 'Verified',
      title: getMessageByKey('explore.verified'),
      image: <VerifiedFilter style={styles.queryImage} />,
      selectedImage: <VerifiedWhiteFilter style={styles.queryImage} />,
      dataFunc_Chefs: getVerified_Chefs,
      dataFunc_Recipes: getVerified_Recipes,
    },
  };

  const {contentLoading, ...exploreData} = useSelector(({explore}) => explore);

  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(
    categories.chefs.name,
  );
  const [selectedQuery, setSelectedQuery] = useState(queries.trending);
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);

  const onRefresh = useCallback(async () => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    selectedQuery[`dataFunc_${selectedCategory}`]();
    setRefreshing(false);
  }, [refreshing]);

  const exploreListData = useMemo(() => {
    const selected = selectedQuery?.name?.toLowerCase() + '_chefs';
    if (selectedCategory === categories.chefs.name) {
      return  exploreData[selected];
    } else {
      return exploreData[selectedQuery?.name?.toLowerCase()];
    }
  }, [exploreData])

  // const totalData = exploreListData?.length
  //   ? exploreListData
  //       ?.map(({exploreListData}) => exploreListData.length)
  //       .reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue)
  //   : 0;

  const followUser = (_id) => {
    follow(_id)
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch(updateUserAction(res.currentUser));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('@@@res', err);
      });
  };

  const unFollowUser = (_id) => {
    unFollow(_id)
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch(updateUserAction(res.currentUser));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('@@@res', err);
      });
  };

  const debouncedFollow = useRef(debounce(followUser, 500));
  const debouncedUnFollow = useRef(debounce(unFollowUser, 500));

  //method that handles Category Click
  const handleCategoryClick = (categoryName) => {
    setSelectedCategory(categoryName);
  };

  //method that handles Query Click
  const handleQueryClick = (query) => {
    setSelectedQuery(query);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Rerendering');
    if(!contentLoading){
      console.log('Updating');
      selectedQuery[`dataFunc_${selectedCategory}`]();
    }
  }, [selectedCategory, selectedQuery]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: isPortrait ? 'column' : 'row',
        }}>
        <LinearGradient
          colors={[
            isDark ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
            isDark ? theme.backgroundColor2 : Colors.veryLightGray,
          ]}
          style={[
            styles.exploreHeader,
            {
              backgroundColor: isDark
                ? theme.backgroundColor2
                : Colors.veryLightGray,
            },
          ]}>
          <View style={styles.searchBarContainer}>
            <SearchBar
              onPress={async () => {
                await analytics().logEvent('search_users_button_clicked');
                if (selectedCategory == 'Chefs') {
                  navigateTo('Search', {type: 'Users'})();
                } else {
                  navigateTo('Search')();
                }
              }}
              placeholder={getMessageByKey('whatShow')}
            />
          </View>

          <View style={styles.categoriesContainer}>
            <CategoriesFilter
              categories={categories}
              handleCategoryClick={handleCategoryClick}
              selectedCategory={selectedCategory}
              theme={theme}
            />
          </View>

          <View style={styles.queriesContainer}>
            <QueryFilter
              queries={queries}
              handleQueryClick={handleQueryClick}
              selectedQuery={selectedQuery}
            />
          </View>
        </LinearGradient>
        {exploreListData && exploreListData.length > 0 && !contentLoading ? (
          <View style={styles.dataContainer}>
            <FlatList
              showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
              data={exploreListData}
              ListFooterComponent={<CategoryBar navigateTo="ChefByCategory" />}
              refreshing={contentLoading}
              refreshControl={
                <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
              }
              contentContainerStyle={styles.listStyles}
              renderItem={({item}) => {
                if (selectedCategory === 'Chefs') {
                  return (
                    <View>
                      <SwiperFlatList
                        autoplay={false}
                        showPagination={false}
                        paginationActiveColor={Colors.smokeWhite}
                        paginationDefaultColor={Colors.salmonOrange}>
                        { 
                          item.recipes.map((recipeData) => {
                            return (
                              // <View style={{marginHorizontal: 0}}>
                              <UserRecipe
                                followUser={debouncedFollow.current}
                                unFollowUser={debouncedUnFollow.current}
                                containerStyles={styles.recipeStyle}
                                item={{recipe: recipeData}}
                                // </View>
                              />
                            )
                          })
                        }
                      </SwiperFlatList>
                    </View>
                  );
                } else {
                  return (
                    <RecipeCard containerStyles={{marginTop: 0}} item={item} />
                  );
                }
              }}
            />
          </View>
        ) : (
          <View>
            {contentLoading || !selectedQuery ? (
              <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
                <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor}}>
                  <UserLoader show />
                  {/* <RecipeCardLoader show /> */}
                </View>
              </View>
            ) : null}
          </View>
        )}
        {!exploreListData?.length && !contentLoading ? (
          <View
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            width: '100%',
            height: SCREEN_HEIGHT,
            top: HEADER_HEIGHT,
          }}>
          <View
            style={{
              height: SCREEN_HEIGHT - HEADER_HEIGHT,
              backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor,
              paddingTop: 20,
            }}>
            <EmptyList svg={<Chefhat width={wp(40)} height={hp(30)} />} />
          </View>
        </View>
        ) : null}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default Explore;
```